# How to show sorted geom_line in R for a combined plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frame and would like to make a combined geom_line plot in R, but it confused on month names, the R suppose the month as text.

I have two df named **ctrans**  :

```
structure(list(month = structure(1:20, levels = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68"), class = "factor"), 
    sd = c(3.56526452189892, 3.23178657161089, 3.68781778291716, 
    2.90784379834192, 1.95505043981536, 1.57762127549323, 1.7763883459299, 
    1.30170827931778, 0.83452296039628, 1.30930734141595, 1.16496474502144, 
    1.16496474502144, 0.991031208965115, 0.786795792469443, 1.2724180205607, 
    1.11269728052837, 0.577350269189626, 0.690065559342354, 0.487950036474267, 
    1.03279555898864), mean = c(17.6, 16, 11.6, 7.7, 4.6, 3.4, 
    2.4, 1.77777777777778, 1.875, 1.5, 1.25, 1.75, 1.125, 1.57142857142857, 
    1.57142857142857, 1.28571428571429, 1, 1.14285714285714, 
    1.28571428571429, 1.66666666666667)), row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19"), class = "data.frame")
```

and **cvhec** :

```
structure(list(month = structure(1:20, levels = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70"
), class = "factor"), sd = c(1.63299316185545, 1.70782512765993, 
2.16024689946929, 1.91485421551268, 2.38047614284762, 1.15470053837925, 
1.70782512765993, 1.73205080756888, 1.4142135623731, 1.82574185835055, 
0.957427107756338, 1.5, 0.816496580927726, 1.70782512765993, 
1.73205080756888, 2.06155281280883, 1.52752523165195, 2.08166599946613, 
3.05505046330389, 2.08166599946613), mean = c(19, 18.25, 19, 
18.5, 18.5, 18, 19.25, 17.5, 18, 18, 18.75, 18.75, 19, 19.75, 
19.5, 19.25, 18.3333333333333, 18.6666666666667, 19.6666666666667, 
19.6666666666667)), row.names = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19"), class = "data.frame")
```

my code for creating plot is :

```
   ggplot(data=ctrans,aes(x = reorder(month, sort(as.numeric(month))) ,y=mean))+
  geom_line(data = ctrans, aes(x = reorder(month, sort(as.numeric(month))), y = mean,group = 1), color = "blue") +
  geom_errorbar(data=ctrans,aes(ymin=mean-sd,ymax=mean+sd,group = 1),colour="green") +
  
  geom_line(data = cvhec, aes(x = reorder(month, sort(as.numeric(month))), y = mean,group = 1), color = "red") +
  geom_errorbar(data=cvhec,aes(ymin=mean-sd,ymax=mean+sd,group = 1),colour="green")+
    xlab('Month') +
    ylab('Score')
```

I got this plot which is not working for me, it shows the X-axis like 0,1,10,11,12,...2,20,21 which is sorted by name not number.

[image]

Comment: Why not just convert month to numeric before you create the plot? Or to `factor(as.numeric(month))` if you want to keep the x axis discrete?

Comment: I have used the following line but it was not worked for me:                                  `ctrans$month <- factor(as.numeric(ctrans$month))`

Comment: You need to control the `levels=` and force the order. Every question in `ggplot2` that asks about "order of ..." is resolved with `factor(.., levels=..)`. Since R's default behavior is to order the unique levels alphabetically, "59" comes before "6", so we need to control it manually. Try `factor(ctrans$month, levels=unique(ctrans$month)[order(as.numeric(unique(ctrans$month)))])`. See the dupe links for much more info on this.

Comment: Ahm MMM, if the dupe-links do not help, please come back and @-ping me and we'll sort through your code to resolve it. (It would help to have a little more sample data for that, if so then please add the output from `dput(head(ctrans,20))` to a code block. Thanks, and good luck!)

Comment: dear @r2evans I have edited and add data to question.

Comment: When I try the code on your recently-edited data, I see that `Month` is sorted numerically (and the `levels=` show that as well). Is it not working some other way?

Comment: It works when I run just one geom_line, since I run the multiple it does not work properly, and consider the number as character again.